# Choppy scrolling on new retina mac book pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac

My new mac has:

> 2.2GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.4GHz 16GB 1600MHz DDR3L SDRAM 256GB PCIe-based Flash Storage Intel Iris Pro Graphics
>   Force Touch trackpad Backlit Keyboard (English) & User's Guide
>   Accessory Kit

But when I scroll this (or other pdf) in safari [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutolayoutPG.pdf)

it looks not smooth when you scroll it. But my mac book MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) has smooth scrolling.

Actually on my new retina mac if I open gmail via safari and try to scroll over 20 emails in list it also stuck when scrolling. Like it's from 1995 years computer.

So I tried it on 10 computer in apple store and all of them have the same problem when scroll link above or gmail content in safari.

Why? (

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with my late 2013 mbpr especially with gmail but also with the link you posted when scrolling fast...

Comment: @doovers, yea when we scroll so fast it seems like very very chopping